# Windev : "Null" Value in DataBase

Tags: windev

I have a problem with **Null** Value.

I Explain.  Here is the below code :

> ChnToto is a chain
>
> ChnToto = Null

On debugging, we find that Windev has stored a "0" (zero) in "ChnToto".

I totally lose the initial information (=> "Null").

How to force the compiler to keep this information without having to use the "Variant" type?

I feel that you have to go through a complex variable, or a class.

Thanks for your advices or ideas

Answer (score 1):

You must use the variant type if you want to handle the null value. 
In windev the string type handle 0 and null the same way.
https://doc.windev.com/en-US/?1511015&verdisp=210

Answer (score 0):

To assign Null Values in DataBase you have to use this syntax:

```
ChnToto..Null = True
```

Then use HModify(), HSave(), HAdd(), Etc.

Avoid ChnToto = null. That is an incorrect assignment of null